# Nonlinear regression analysis of a vector

Tags: functions, matlab, regression, vector-analysis, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to get a nonlinear fit of a vector in Matlab with no success.

Let's assume that I have a vector called data:

```
data = [1,30,250,55,22,76]
```

which can be seen as a function like

```
f(0)=data[0]
f(1)=data[1]
```

and so on.

[This is how it looks on WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eovkbhs8ti0)

I want to make a nonlinear regression of this function/array with Matlab but the documentation is not helping me as it says something about `DataSet` or `Matrix` and I don't know how to get there starting from my simple array.

So the question is:

how can I make a nonlinear regression, in Matlab, starting from a given vector that can be seen as a function?

EDIT:
As an extra, is it possible to have an array containing all the residuals in this form?

```
residuals[0]=residual of data[0]
```

EDIT 2:
The output should be a function like this [WolframAlpha result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e1u4r2ui897)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create x data values

```
 x_data=[1 2 3 4 5 6]';
```

Create y data values

```
y_data=[1 30 250 55 22 76]';
```

Create custom fit function

```
g = fittype( @(a, b, c, d, e, x) a*x.^4+b*x.^3+c*x.^2+d*x+e );
```

Fit the data

```
[cfun,gof,output] = fit( x_data, y_data, g );
```

Display the coefficients

```
cfun
```

Display the residuals

```
output.residuals
```